# AngularJS: ng-repeat filter property before orderBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

Can I add extra filters to an orderBy clause in ng-repeat to process a given value before orderBy does its job?

I have an md-select like this

```
  <md-option ng-repeat="element in list | orderBy: 'name': reverse" 
             ng-value="element">
    <span>{{element.name | translate}}</span>
  </md-option>
```

This sorts by the underlying 'name' (like ENUM_ACCEPT, ENUM_CANCEL...) but not by the rendered name after translation (Accept, Cancel...) which may change depending on language, thus, order should change too.

Comment: try it data-ng-repeat="element in list | orderBy:'name | translate' "

Comment: Didn't work. Only way it seems to work is to pass a method which basically does `function translated() {return $translate.instant(elem.name);}`. The html is then `ng-repeat="element in list | orderBy: translated : reverse"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  <md-option ng-repeat="element in list | translate for element in list | orderBy: 'name': reverse" 
         ng-value="element">
  <span>{{element.name | translate}}</span>
 </md-option>
```

The reason for what you are facing is the options are sorted by their original name not their translated one. Adding `translate for element in list`filter should resolve your issue.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It is producing an empty list. Maybe it runs **| translate** on the entire object element instead of its **name** property?

Comment: this all depends on how you translate. I just put a generic idea of how this can be done

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="element in list | translate for element in list | orderBy: 'name | translate': reverse" 
         ng-value="element">
  <span>{{element.name | translate}}</span>
 </md-option>
```